# Facebook connect won't display the Facebook page

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

I have a facebook application I got from  a web named mobisoft. I import the project and do all according to what the web said. My project contain no error and I ran it normally. But when the application ran it didn't display the facebook page.
Here is the log cat

```
08-25 16:56:20.597: INFO/System.out(337): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-25 16:56:20.807: INFO/System.out(337): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-25 16:56:20.807: DEBUG/MediaScannerService(261): done scanning volume external
08-25 16:56:21.028: INFO/System.out(337): waiting for debugger to settle...
08-25 16:56:21.232: INFO/System.out(337): debugger has settled (1393)
08-25 16:56:21.697: DEBUG/dalvikvm(337): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
08-25 16:56:23.307: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Displayed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: +35s490ms
08-25 16:56:28.064: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-25 16:56:28.739: WARN/ActivityManager(68): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{40540af8 com.codecarpet.fbconnect.sample/.MainActivity}
08-25 17:01:01.288: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
08-25 17:01:56.547: INFO/InputReader(68): Device reconfigured: id=0x0, name=qwerty2, display size is now 480x800
08-25 17:01:56.547: INFO/InputManager-Callbacks(68): No virtual keys found for device qwerty2.
08-25 17:01:57.057: INFO/ARMAssembler(68): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00001004_00000000 [ 65 ipp] (85 ins) at [0x445ed520:0x445ed674] in 960759 ns
08-25 17:01:57.127: INFO/ARMAssembler(68): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 91 ipp] (114 ins) at [0x445ed678:0x445ed840] in 632898 ns
08-25 17:06:01.337: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
08-25 17:11:01.363: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
08-25 17:16:01.407: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
08-25 17:18:05.437: DEBUG/FBSession(337): FBUserId = 0
08-25 17:18:41.369: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Displayed com.codecarpet.fbconnect.sample/.MainActivity: +22m23s181ms
08-25 17:18:41.518: INFO/ARMAssembler(68): generated scanline__00000177:03515104_00001002_00000000 [ 87 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x445ed848:0x445eda00] in 530195 ns
08-25 17:21:01.449: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your firewall. i think your firewall blocks the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Recently one of our apps in production broke because Facebook changed something in their API but have not updated the Facebook for Android SDK in a while.

Your app might be using this SDK. If it is you will need to debug the SDK, if it isn't then maybe you could try to use it.

There is a Github repository for the Facebook for Android SDK and for instance the bug that we had was https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/pull/218. You might find your issue was already found by a Github user but you will need to debug the SDK, if you are indeed using it.